# Counting characters in a string

Tags: c++, string, loops

My code runs and works well the first time around, but I am having looping problems:

1. My code isn't counting characters that are in words
2. The second time around when you press "yes," it ends up printing everything out. I must have a loop in the wrong spot, but I can't find it for the life of me.

```
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char character;
    string sentence;
    char answer;
    int cCount;
    while(1) {

        cout << "Enter a character to count the number of times it is in a sentence: ";
        cin >> character;
        cout << "Enter a sentence and to search for a specified character: ";
        cin >> sentence;
        if(character == '\n' || sentence.empty())
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid answer:\n";
            break;

        }
        else {
            cCount = count(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), character);
            cout << "Your sentence had" << " " << cCount << " " << character << " " << "character(s)" << '\n'; 
         }

    cout << "Do you wish to enter another sentence (y/n)?: \n";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n'){
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should take care of not reading user 'return' as character. After both character reads, you should type cin.ignore().

Answer (score 2):

By just reading your code, it looks fine, except where you get the sentence. Using cin, it will only read until it sees a newline or a space, so if you're entering a sentence, it will read every word as a different input.

Try getline(cin, sentence) and see if that fixes the problem.

Edit: Forgot to add in: use cin.ignore() after the getline. cin reads up to, and including the line break (or space) while getline only reads up to the line break, so the line break is still in the buffer.

Comment: Oh, and make you code work in case they enter 'N' as well. Just a usability tip.

Comment: You don't need to call `ignore` after `getline`.  You need to call it before.  `getline` does read the new line character, but discards it.  It's `operator>>` which will stop before the new line, leaving it in the buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I get it mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
cin.ignore();  //dont forget to use cin.ignore() as it will clear all previous cin
getline(cin, sentence, '\n'); //take the sentence upto \n i.e entered is pressed
```

Comment: `cin.ignore()` will not clear all previous input.  Just 1 character.  But you can pass a value to tell it to get more. Technically, it doesn't really clear anything.  It reads characters from the stream, just like any other input function, but discards them instead of parsing and storing them.

Comment: exactly, that was english problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the loops wrong. What's wrong is that you are assuming that

```
cin >> sentence;
```

does something different from what it really does.

If you want to read a line of text, then do this

```
getline(cin, sentnence);
```

Your code reads a single word only.

Comment: I had that at first but it compiles but doesnt do its job. after i enter a character i get:Enter a sentence and to search for a specified character: Please enter a valid answer:

Comment: @user2939276 It's a valid answer, just not a complete answer. You have some more things to learn about input in C++. If you did a little research (instead of you expecting people to spoon feed you working code) you would know that getline is correct. `ignore` is the piece you are missing, some of the other answers mention this.

Answer (score 0):

use `cin` it will end with a newline or a space 
eg:
when you input `hello world` it will get `hello`

and you can try 
`getline`

it wiil end with a newline

Answer (score 0):

This is working, try this.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char character;
    string sentence;
    char answer;
    int cCount;
    while(1) {

        cout << "Enter a character to count the number of times it is in a sentence: ";
        cin >> character;
        cout << "Enter a sentence and to search for a specified character: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin, sentence, '\n');
        if(character == '\n' || sentence.empty())
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid answer:\n";
            break;

        }
        else {
            cCount = count(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), character);
            cout << "Your sentence had" << " " << cCount << " " << character << " " << "character(s)" << '\n';
         }

    cout << "Do you wish to enter another sentence (y/n)?: \n";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'n'){
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

after you enter first input and enter that enter is considered as input in sentence
So, you need to flush that and after that you can scan that sentence.

Comment: Sorry but `fflush(stdin)` is implementation defined behaviour. It may flush the input on your system, but that isn't guaranteed to be the case on every system. It only has well defined behaviour on output streams.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
cCount = count(sentence.c_str(), sentence.c_str()+sentence.length(), character);
```